# Why do you have to wrap a callback with an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, fadein, fadeout

My html contains two forms overlapping each other, one used as add form and one as edit form. I use jQuery to show and hide them with the following code:

```
var editForm = $("#edit-form");
var addForm = $("#add-form");

var showEditForm = function() {
    editForm.fadeIn(function() {
        addForm.fadeOut();
    });
};
var showAddForm = function() {
    editForm.fadeOut(function() {
        addForm.fadeIn();
    });
};
```

I wanted to make the code more compact so I set the `fadeOut()` call directly on the `fadeOut()` callback by doing like this:

```
var showEditForm = function() {
    editForm.fadeIn(addForm.fadeOut);
};
var showAddForm = function() {
    editForm.fadeOut(addForm.fadeIn);
};
```

But this productes the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Valid arities are: [1], but 4 arguments provided.` but why doesn't that work?

Comment: You have to supply a function so the higher order function fadeout will be able to trigger it. this answer can range from monads to syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `addForm.fadeOut` is being called with a bad combination of arguments, when its passed to the `fadeIn` function (and vice versa).

The classic example of this pitfall seems to be:

```
["0", "1", "2", "3"].map(function(i) {return parseInt(i);})
```

This, works as expected and gives `[1,2,3,4]` as a result.  You might expect that you could shorten this, much as you did above, and write

```
["0", "1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt);
```

Unfortunately; this evaluates to `[0, NaN, NaN, NaN]`.  The problem, is that `.map` calls any function provided it with three arguments: the value, the index, and the array itself, and `parseInt` takes up to two arguments: the value, but also the radix/base to parse in.  (e.g. radix 2 to parse a string as binary)  So what actually happens is essentially:

```
[
    parseInt("0", 0), //0, radix is ignored
    parseInt("1", 1), //NaN, what is base 1?
    parseInt("2", 2), //NaN, 2 isn't valid binary
    parseInt("3", 3)  //NaN, 3 isn't valid ternary/base-3
]
```

I suspect, based on the error message, that the same thing is going on here.  The "arity" of a function is the number of arguments passed to it, so the error message here says that 4 arguments were provided, when only one was expected.

In general with functions that take optional arguments, you need to be careful before passing them to other functions directly, or else you can't control what arguments it will be called with.

Comment: This was indeed producing the error. Using `addForm.fadeOut(function() { editForm.fadeIn.apply(this, arguments); });` threw the exact same error

Answer (score 8):

That's because calling a function as a property of an object is a special syntax, that calls the function with the object as context.

When you call a function like this:

```
obj.func();
```

then `this` will be a reference to `obj` inside the function.

If you get the reference to the function, and then call it:

```
var f = obj.func;
f();
```

then `this` will be a reference to the global context, i.e. the `window` object.

By using `editForm.fadeIn(addForm.fadeOut);` you get the reference to `addForm.fadeOut` and send to the `fadeIn` method. It's no longer associated with the object, so it will be called with the global context instead of the object as context.

You can use the `proxy` method to associate the function with the object, so that it will be called with the correct context:

```
var showEditForm = function() {
  editForm.fadeIn($.proxy(addForm.fadeOut, addForm));
};
var showAddForm = function() {
  editForm.fadeOut($.proxy(addForm.fadeIn, addForm));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmj8tLfm/

`addForm.fadeIn` and `addForm.fadeOut` are being called without specifying the `this` context that would normally be passed when you call `addForm.fadeIn()`.  Try `.bind()`-ing the this variable appropriately as follows:

```
var showEditForm = function() {
    editForm.fadeIn(addForm.fadeOut.bind(addForm));
};
var showAddForm = function() {
    editForm.fadeOut(addForm.fadeIn.bind(addForm));
};
```

Comment: The [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is not supported in all browsers, so I recommend the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing in vanilla js. The reason as to why you need too pass the callback function in an anonymous function has to do with function invocation.

Take a look at this example:

```
const firstFunc = (callback) => {
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('yes');
  console.log(callback())
 }, 3000);
}

const secondFunc = () => console.log('great');

firstFunc(function(){
 secondFunc();
});

// prints 'yes' 'great' after 3 seconds

> yes
  great
```

When invoking the function, if you pass the callback argument without the parenthesis i.e `firstFunc(secondFunc);` the callback function will invoke after the first function has finished (just like above) provided inside the first function where the callback gets called is invoking that function. i.e `callback()`, the **()** is the important part.

Try omitting the parenthesis inside the first function like this, `callback` and pass the second function as a callback without the parenthesis `firstFunction(secondFunction)` notice how you are passing the callback function but it is never being invoked. Your console.log() should look like this.

```
> yes
  () => console.log('great')
```

So why does this matter...

If you pass the function invocation as `firstFunc(secondFunc())` using the setup from the first code snippet. You will notice that the second function prints first then 3 seconds later the first function is invoked.

```
> great
  yes
```

Given that Javascript is event driven, the invocation of the second function can be found `const secondFunc = () => console.log('great');` and it will immediately invoke that function not waiting for the response from the first function. That is what the **()** did when you invoked secondFunc() inside firstFunc.

By passing an anonymous function that function is never being invoked until it reaches the callback() invocation part. Again using the setup from the first code snippet, try.

```
firstFunc(function(){
 secondFunc();
});

firstFunc(function(){
 secondFunc();
}())
```

See how the second call invokes the secondFunc right away. What is happening is the anonymous function is a wrapper to not invoke your function right away.

Why is this useful?
If secondFunc takes a callback that callback function would not be invoked until the second function has finished executing. You would need to call that callback function inside your second function.

```
firstFunc(function(){
 secondFunc(function(){
  thirdFunc();
 });
});
```